# cannot use primitive.D literal (type primitive.D) as type primitive.E in slice literal

Tags: go, bson

I am attempting to push a slice to my MongoDB database. The data I am attempting to push is a struct with the following fields:

```
type GroupMember struct {
    GroupID   string `json:"group_id" bson:"group_id"`
    Children  []string `json:"children" bson:"children"`
}
```

Basically, I add elements to my `Children` slice (initializing it if nil), set my `GroupID`, and then need to push the updated data to MongoDB. I have tried the following:

```
_, err = uc.UpdateOne(ctx, bson.M{"_id": dbu.ID}, bson.D{{"$set", bson.D{{"group_id", dbu.GroupID}}}, bson.D{{"$set", bson.D{{"children", dbu.Children}}}}})
```

where `dbu` is a `GroupMember` instance. However, I keep running into the error:

```
cannot use primitive.D literal (type primitive.D) as type primitive.E in slice literal
```

I have tried playing around with different ways of doing this based on what I have read online but I am not sure what the right approach is with regards to preparing a slice for upload as `bson`. According to the MongoDB documentation, `bson.A` is the bson equivalent to an array so I tried wrapping my data with `bson.A{}` but I get the same error. I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update document is not well-formed. Try this instead:

```
bson.M{"$set":bson.M{"group_id":dbu.GroupID,"children": dbu.Children}}
```